# Variable doesn't change value in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have html page with

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-view>Some content</div>

  myVar: {{myVar}}
</div>
```

And angular controller:

```
myModule.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
   $scope.myVar = false;

   $scope.someAction = function() {
     $location.path('/anotherPath');
     $scope.myVar = true; // changes in controller, but not in view
   }
});
```

My module is

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
     .when('/anotherPath', {
       templateUrl: 'anotherPath.html',
       controller: 'MyCtrl'
     })

     .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/anotherPath.html'
     })
});
```

`anotherPath.html`contains only

```
<input data-ng-click="someAction()" type="button" class="btn" value="Some action">
```

After clicking on this input controller changes path, but in view value of `myVar` is still `false`. Why?

Comment: Try reversing the statements in `someAction`

Comment: Try putting "$scope.myVar = true;" statement before the "$location.path"

Comment: Does the template from `anotherPath` have another controller defined for it that would be a child scope and hence doesn't have `myVar` in its $scope?

Comment: @StephenKaiser It should inherit from MyCtrl anyway, but it might have redeclared `myVar`?

Comment: @RGraham You're right. If he has redeclared it like you pointed out, it overrides the parent scope's value and he will need to use $scope.$parent.myVar. @baxxabit Can you post your template from `anotherPath`? That might give us more information to help you.

Comment: Rather than using $scope.$parent.myVar, declare it like $scope.model.myVar. That way the child controller will be able to change it. More on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/957731

Comment: $scope.$parent will be extremely brittle, as it will break as soon as the inheritance-chain is changed.

Comment: @StephenKaiser, sure, my template contains only `<input data-ng-click="someAction()" type="button" class="btn" value="Some action">`, nothing else

Comment: @baxxabit Does your route have a controller?

Comment: Updated question to be more clear. @RGraham

Comment: @FizerKhan, without changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you have defined your controller twice. Once on the parent div:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
```

And once on the route for `/anotherPath`:

```
$routeProvider
     .when('/anotherPath', {
       templateUrl: 'anotherPath.html',
       controller: 'MyCtrl' <-- This will be assigned to <div ng-view>
     })
```

Leaving you with something like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-view ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    </div>
</div>
```

Therefore, when you call `$scope.someAction()` you are calling the function defined on the controller assigned to your *inner view*, rather than the function defined on the parent controller.

You should give your View its own unique controller in the route definition:

**Angular:**

```
$routeProvider
     .when('/anotherPath', {
       templateUrl: 'anotherPath.html',
       controller: function($scope) {
           // You don't necessarily need an implementation here
       }
     })
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-view>Some content</div>

  myVar: {{myVar}}
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, I missed this point. I can remove ng-controller declaration from html, will it work?

Comment: No, you can't do that either because then `myVar` would not be defined in *any* scope. Simply set the controller in your route definition to an empty implementation, it will by default inherit from the parent `MyCtrl` so you have full access to its functions and variables

Comment: Thanks, I'm a newbie in angular :) 
Is it necessary or can I remove it
 `controller: function($scope) {}`

Comment: No problem, it's a tough framework to get to grips with! You'd need to check the docs to confirm, but I think a view must have a controller :)

Comment: Great, thanks again, I haven't skills in english to express my appreciation :)

Comment: Working as expected now. controller declaration in this case is optional